# Bootstrap 4 - Grid 1 and 2 Change position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Example what i need:

Image:

[image]

My code is this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail float-left" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block" alt="Belgrade">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail float-right" alt="Niš">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- THIS IS PROBLEM -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- THIS COLUMN NEED TO BE BELOW 1 COLUMN / LEFT SIDE -->
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail float-left" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
            <!-- THIS COLUMN NEED TO BE BELOW 3 COLUMN / RIGHT SIDE -->
            <div class="col-3 ml-auto">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail float-right" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PROBLEM -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail float-left" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="image1.png" class="img-thumbnail float-right" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can't figure where is the problem. If someone know where problem is, write solution. Thanks

PS. Sorry for my Bad english

Thanks All..

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I've updated my answer to include background images, and to mimic the original layout better. Thanks to AndreiGheorghiu for help answering this more accurately.

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:10px;
  height:500px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr .2fr 1fr .2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "topLeft large large large topRight"
                       "midLeft large large large midRight"
                       "bottomLeft bottomLeft bottomCenter bottomRight bottomRight";
}

.pic{
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/400/400/any) no-repeat center/cover;
  font: 700 20px sans-serif;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  text-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;
}

.pic-1{
   grid-area: topLeft;
}

.pic-2{
   grid-area: large;
}

.pic-3{
   grid-area: topRight;
}

.pic-4{
   grid-area: midLeft;
}

.pic-5{
   grid-area: midRight;
}

.pic-6{
   grid-area: bottomLeft;
}

.pic-7{
   grid-area: bottomCenter;
}

.pic-8{
   grid-area: bottomRight;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="pic pic-1">Foxwoods</div>
  <div class="pic pic-2">New York City</div>
  <div class="pic pic-3">Las Vegas</div>
  <div class="pic pic-4">Philadelphia</div>
  <div class="pic pic-5">San Francisco</div>
  <div class="pic pic-6">Miami</div>
  <div class="pic pic-7">Boston</div>
  <div class="pic pic-8">Washington D.C.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu how is it not responsive?

Comment: At least now I know it's not you who voted down initially, but Sanu, who basically copied my answer 16 minutes later and voted mine down.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you are the one who first criticized me. You said my solution was not "responsive," but your definition is not sufficient. My solution shrinks or expands in the viewport responsively. If you meant it doesn't change the layout in some way, how it should be changed needs to be specified. Plus your response is not any more responsive than mine, and is incomplete and has no working demo.

Comment: You're correct. I didn't pay enough attention. If you fix the sizing problem of your grid, you'll probably have my up-vote. I'll also remove the previous comments as they're based on a wrong assumption.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu That's ok. I did downvote you out of annoyance, so if you edit your answer I can upvote it (my vote is currently locked). I'll also edit my answer to fix the sizing problem.

Comment: To make it most useful for future users, you might want to add in technique to size the image to fit (either `background-size` or `object-fit`). I will edit my answer with a proper solution that doesn't need hard-coded `height` on the cell size, using `flexbox`. That's a nice little challenge before I sign off. Take care and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the small images in the same col. And display them as blocks: `display:block; width: 100%; height: auto;`.

Here's how I'd personally do it. I'm using `.no-gutter` class on `.row`s and white borders on images:

```css
[my-gallery]:not(#_) {
  padding: 8px;
}
[my-gallery] img {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 8px solid white;
}
[my-gallery] .strethed img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid" my-gallery>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200/?random" alt="Novi Sad">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/303/202/?random" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 strethed">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/306/204/?random" alt="Belgrade">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/309/206/?random" alt="Niš">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/312/208/?random" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters" >
            <div class="col">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/315/210/?random" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/318/212/?random" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/321/214/?random" alt="Novi Sad">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code,

> *Note: Included responsive classes. Run this code as a full page*

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Novi Sad">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail mt-md-4" alt="Novi Sad">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Belgrade">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Niš">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail mt-md-4" alt="Novi Sad">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Novi Sad">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Novi Sad">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Novi Sad">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```